# dynamic update the data using EF4 in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

for example, i have a data table named [User], and mapping to User enetity with EF4:

```
Id, FullName, EmailAddress, Fax, Tel
```

in the web page, i just only want to update the "EmailAddess" and "Fax" 2 properties below:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User"))
{
    <label>Email Address:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("EmailAddress")
    <label>Fax:</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Fax")
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

and controller i did for this:

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user) {

var _user = GetUsers().Where(a => a.Id == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();

_user.Fax = user.Fax;
_user.EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;

context.SaveChanges();
}
```

yes, i updated it and successful, but next time i also want to update "Tel", so i need to change the code like this:

```
_user.Fax = user.Fax;
_user.EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress;
_user.Tel = user.Tel;
```

if i have 100 fields, i will be crazy for doing it :(

So, how can i only update the models to database for related fields in web page?

thanks

Comment: Your going to have to clarify.  Do you mean to say you have 1000 different forms all updating different properties of the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely look into AutoMapper ( http://automapper.codeplex.com/ ).

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(User), typeof(UserViewModel));

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserViewModel>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Property1, f => f.MapFrom(s => s.Property1))
    .ForMember(d => d.Property2, f => f.MapFrom(s => s.Property2))
    .ForMember(d => d.Property3, f => f.MapFrom(s => s.Property3));
```

Then in your Edit you can do the following

```
public ActionResult Edit(User user) {
    var _user = GetUsers().Where(a => a.Id == user.Id).SingleOrDefault();

    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(user, _user);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Entity framework will only update the fields that have actually changed.

Pretty sure that's about all you need.

Comment: @BuildStarted - This doesn't solve his problem at all. He's still going to have to have to create 1000 viewmodels for each permutation of the form.

Comment: hi, thanks for your comments, for the AutoMapper, it means i need to make the mapper first for 100 fileds:

Comment: Not necessarily. Automapper can infer maps directly - especially if you use the same object. Though reading it I think I see what you mean - I guess I need some clarification - Do you want to have a single Edit Action where you update the fields or are you going to have 100 different actions each updating different fields?

Comment: The last part of your question lead me to believe you were just going to update the function with the new fields not create new functions.

Comment: @jfar haha, you are joking, i will have 3~5 viewmodels.

Comment: @GBK - Oh, from your question I thought you had tons; "if i have 100 fields, i will be crazy for doing it".  So whats the problem here?  This is in the "I do this every day" category.

Comment: @BuildStarted only one Edit action to update the different fields

Comment: Yeah, you can do it by hand easily enough - just takes a bit of time. You could also use AutoMapper which will map fields automagically for you (sometimes without having to create a map). (I use excel to sorta automate this kind of stuff because of it's great paste columns ability and what not)

Comment: @jfar sorry for my unclear description. and @BuildStarted , my purpose is, different users browse the form (same web form), and they can edit different fields by authority, some people can edit the EmailAddress and Fax, but another people can edit EmailAddress, Fax, Tel, so i will use @Html.DisplayFor("Tel") to show the data for the people who no access to edit Tel, but if i use the same Edit action for update, the Tel will be set to null or empty.

Comment: @GBK - How do you tell what form fields each user can edit?  Stored in a db, config or are you wiring this up manually?